# C++ - QSettings question

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

> Does `Qt` has something like `QSettings`, but for **local** scopes?

*I am seeking for a data structure with the same methods, but not specific for APPLICATION.*

I mean, I want to construct local (for example, *exporting settings*) settings from file (`xml`, for example) and use them in *local scope* - **without polluting global application settings.**

*Is that possible (with `QSettings` or some other class)? How should I construct the object then?*

Comment: What do you mean by global application settings? Do you mean where the settings are stored on disk or the QSettings object in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
void QSettings::setPath ( Format format, Scope scope, const QString & path )
```

to set the format (as specified in the [doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsettings.html#Format-enum))

> QSettings::NativeFormat 0 Store the
>   settings using the most appropriate
>   storage format for the platform. On
>   Windows, this means the system
>   registry; on Mac OS X, this means the
>   CFPreferences API; on Unix, this means
>   textual configuration files in INI
>   format.
>
> QSettings::IniFormat 1 Store the
>   settings in INI files.
>
> QSettings::InvalidFormat

the scope:

> QSettings::UserScope 0 Store settings
>   in a location specific to the current
>   user (e.g., in the user's home
>   directory).
>
> QSettings::SystemScope 1 Store
>   settings in a global location, so that
>   all users on the same machine access
>   the same set of settings.

So if you are on Windows and want to write User-specific settings, you would use the IniFormat and the UserScope values and specify the path where you want to write your settings in the path variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You create a datastream and write the data into the file in member by member fashion.